# How to create email templates in React JS using Rails as backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, email, email-templates

Has anyone have any idea to create email templates in React JS using Rails as backend

Answer (score 3):

Please use this plugin

```
npm install react-html-email
```

To render a simple email:

```
import { Email, Item, Span, A, renderEmail } from 'react-html-email'
const emailHTML = renderEmail(
<Email title="Hello World!">
  <Item align="center">
    <Span fontSize={20}>
      This is an example email made with:
      <A href="#">react-html- 
        email</A>.
    </Span>
  </Item>
</Email>
)
```